# Converting timezone from UTC to ET in PHP

Tags: php, timezone, localhost

I tried to convert timezone from UTC to ET .It is working perfectly fine in my local host(windows) but in Production(Linux server) when I convert UTC(1:20 pm ) to ET.File_date is showing as 9.20 AM. Any idea as why it is showing wrong time?

```
            $original_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $original_timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

            $datetime = new DateTime($original_datetime, $original_timezone);

            $target_timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');

            $datetime->setTimeZone($target_timezone);

            $file_date = $datetime->format("m-d-Y g:i A");
```

Answer (score 1):

**That is not the wrong time.**

Eastern Time and UTC are four hours apart at the moment.  1:20 PM in UTC is 9:20 AM in Eastern US Time (ET).  So the results you're getting in production are correct.

Step through this code on your local host, and check each of the variables you use. See which one is being set incorrectly.  Then you'll know where the problem lies.

I suspect the problem is that the first line should be a call to `gmdate()` instead of `date()`.  `gmdate()` gives you the current time in GMT, but `date()` gives it to your in your local time.  This could be the difference if your production server is set to GMT/UTC by default.

I would like to reiterate, however, that it is your local result that is incorrect - not your production result.  9:20 AM is the proper conversion of 1:20 PM from UTC to America/New_York.

Comment: "Eastern Time and UTC are four hours apart" - at the moment. They're five hours apart when standard time is being observed.

Comment: What is showing up as 2:20 PM?  The UTC time or the Eastern Time?

Comment: @ErickRobertson file_date is showing up as 2.20PM in localhost and as 9.20 AM in production.